# In Eclipse, is there a view that shows members of the currently selected element

Tags: java, eclipse

When I have an interface or class open in the editor, I can see all the members in the outline.  The "Javadoc" view shows the docs of the element currently selected - whatever I click on.

I want a combination of these views.  I want to see all members of the currently selected element.  I know I can see them if I declare a variable and bring up the content assist.  But that is too cumbersome.  I want to click on an element, see its vivible methods and attributes in a view without loading the file into the main editor window.

Can it be done?

Comment: `Ctrl + F3` opens a popup with the outline of the current element, with focus in a search field. Very useful.

Comment: @Baldrick this should be an answer. Very useful indeed. I would prefer this functionality as a permanent view just like the Javadoc view

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to open a popup with the outline of the current element, with focus in a search field. I think it's the most useful. Skike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to get also inherited members in the same popup.

You can also use <kbd>F4</kbd> to quickly open a the type hierarchy view on the selected element. This view contains the subtype and/or supertype hierarchy of the element, and also the members/methods of the element (and its parents with the button 'show all inherited members').

Comment: I think this might be the closest Eclipse can get to what I was after. Its not quite as convenient as having a view that always shows the members of the current element, but it is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the element in Package explore and see all the methods and variables declared[image]

Comment: This requires finding the element in the tree which is not convenient. I am after a way to quickly see the methods of an element in my editor without opening or navigating to it